# Multithread continue to work, after it is stopped (Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I wrote some code with while loop in it. Then I put it on theread. When I want to stop thread I will change while loop's condition and it will stop. But when I want to continue after stoppping, I can't do it.

I tried to make it recursive. But it takes processor time. How I can do it properly?

```
class Some_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.while_condition = True
        self.mythread = Thread(target=self.do_trade)
    
    def start(self):
        if self.while_condition = False:
            self.while_condition = True
        else: 
            self.mythread.start()
    
    def stop(self):
        self.while_condition = False
    
    def do_action(self):
        while(self.while_condition):
            print("thread is working")
            time.sleep(5)
        print("action stopped")
        self.do_action()
obj = Some_class()
```

I expected the output:

> thread is working
>
> thread is working

after obj.stop()

> action stopped

then obj.start() will continue

> thread is working
>
> thread is working

Comment: You don't have all of the relevant code here but I believe the answer you need is that you cannot restart a stopped thread in Python. Next if you called `start` it doesn't call `do_action` so that would not start printing again. Your while loop ends the first time and nothing tells it to start again.

Comment: Sure, it is not my real code,  only sample. I know what you said, but how I can restart thread?

Comment: You cannot restart a stopped thread. You could create a new thread in order to simulate it or you can not stop the thread and just stop the action inside before passing a command to continue, but if the thread is actually stopped it cannot be restarted.

Comment: @GiraffeMan91Can you try to add your answer, please. How I can add new thread and stop the previous. Previous one should not take any processor time or memory. Thank you

Comment: Check out @Mahmoud Elshahat answer below, it is what I described as starting a new thread. Keep in mind if you need to pass state to the new thread when it starts you will need to first pass it back to main and then on to the new thread. You can use queue or another method to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of wrong things in your code, check the correct code below and find out what was wrong:

Note, threads can only start one time and can not be restarted, so you start new thread every time

```
from threading import Thread
import time

class Some_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.while_condition = True

    def start(self):
        self.while_condition = True
        Thread(target=self.do_action).start()

    def stop(self):
        self.while_condition = False

    def do_action(self):
        while(self.while_condition):
            print("thread is working")
            time.sleep(5)
        print("action stopped")
obj = Some_class()
obj.start()
time.sleep(10)
obj.stop()
time.sleep(5)
print('restarting thread')
obj.start()
```

output:

```
thread is working
thread is working
action stopped
restarting thread
thread is working
thread is working
thread is working
```

Comment: You are right. Thank you.
But it is not the answer for my question

Comment: I think that their question is more about how they can restart a stopped thread, you did fix their pseudocode but that isn't really their issue.

Comment: @GiraffeMan91, look at my answer edit, you can start/stop/restart thread

Comment: Yea that would generally work, it is starting a new thread rather than restarting the old one, which means state wouldn't be saved if that is required state would need to be passed back to the main and then passed in to the new thread when it is started.  But for the example given it will work as asked.

Comment: @NurislomRakhmatullaev, i mean by restarting a thread is starting the same job again but theoretically you can not start thread once it ended

Comment: @GiraffeMan91, yes you are right if he needs to pass states he should use thread safe communication like queues

Comment: @MahmoudElshahat Yes, I don't need to restart that thread. It works. But does it effect to the system? I mean will it use one core, but do nothing. If I start thread, it will use one processor core. After when I change the condition will it stop thread? Will Thread be collected by garbage collector, so it will not effect to the system?

Comment: @NurislomRakhmatullaev, yes the stopped thread will be no longer existed and garbage collected, no effect on the system

Comment: Just to be sure, you understand this is starting a thread in the same process, not a new process in a different core. That would be _multiprocessing_